# NetWeaver JSF rendering document type is not supported

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, lsf, netweaver

I developed a very simple JSF application in SAP NWDS with the "SAP Component Library for JSF".

I run the JSF application (code below) and I get a popup alert with this text:

> Fatal application error: The standard rendering document type is not supported. Contact your administrator

I have no idea what the "standard render document type" is and where I can configure it.

Any ideas or hints?

Regards Kay

JSF application:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sap.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sap.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hallo ?</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h:form>
    <h:messages/>
    <hr>
        <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="First Name" style="color: #808080; font-style: normal; font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-weight: bold"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText value="#{person.name}"></h:inputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="submit"></h:commandButton>  
    </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: It's at least not recognizable as something specific to JSF. Is that really the **exact** error message (i.e. copypasted and no typos/grammar mistakes, etc)? [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="Fatal%20application%20error%3A%20The%20standard%20rendering%20document%20type%20is%20not%20supported.%20Contact%20your%20administrator") does namely also not give any hits on the exact message other than your own question.

Comment: Yes its the exact error message

If the browser language is german it says "Schwerwiegender Anwendungsfehler. Der Standard-Rendering-Dokumenttyp wird nicht unterstützt. Wenden Sie sich an Ihren Systemadministrator"

For both the english and the german message I found nothing. I can click "Ok" and the Application work, but its really annoying to click it away for every page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the line

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

It seems that this LSF-Framework gives the DOCTYPE in the `<f:view>`-Element and the error is related to the second doctype